# Deleting Snapshots from VMWare-VM (Workstation pro)

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have a VM with several Snapshots that has grown to about 150GB, and I desperately need to reduce its size, since the SSD it's saved on is at capacity. I tried deleting snapshots from the snapshot manager, but I got an error message along the lines of "this operation needs 30GB free disk space to complete" -- ok, so apparently consolidation needs disk space. I could copy the VM to an external disk and delete snapshots on there (would that help?), but the thing is- they no longer show up in the snapshot manager. How can I "clean" this VM now?

Comment: Is there anything else on your disk that you could temporarily move to the external disk?  That said, moving the VM to an external disk should work.  If it doesn't, then probably your VM ended up with absolute paths to its files.  If you want to delete *all* snapshots, an alternative would be to create a *full* clone of the VM on the external disk, and then you could delete the original.

Comment: Moving to an external disk did not work (does VMWare maybe cache to the AppData folder?) A full clone is a good idea for when I have given up on retaining the one snapshot that I actually do care about, however so mildly.

Comment: No, the VM's directory should be self-contained (unless you specified in its configuration to use a different "working directory", or unless it's a linked clone of another VM).  There have been cases (bugs) where VMware Workstation used to write absolute paths instead of relative paths to its configuration and disk files, which is most likely what happened to you. (continued...)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know of a good way to fix this.  You could try copying your VM to an external disk and then modifying its `.vmx` and `.vmsd` files to remove all absolute paths (make sure you do this to a copy of a VM in case it doesn't work).  If the `.vmdk` files also use absolute paths, fixing them will probably be trickier.